# Integral approximation of functions not defined for x=0

Tags: taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence, approximate-integration

I have to approximate with an error less than 0.1 this integral:
$$ \int_1^2 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx $$

I understood I have to use the Taylor series, then prove that is uniforme convergence and integrate the "x-dependent" part. Finally I Can use Leibniz to estimate the error (since the series should be a alternate-sign one).

Anyway I am not able to determinate the series since the function is not defined for x_0=0 (so I cannot use McLaurin).

How can I handle this problem?
I have a lot of exercises of this kind and I really don't know how to handle them...please help me!
Thank you!

Comment: $\exp$ is defined on the whole real line: write $$\exp( -x^{-2}) = \sum_n \frac{1}{n!}(-x^{-2})^n = \sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{1}{x^{2n}}$$

Comment: @user202729 Who cares? $0 \notin [1,2]$.

Comment: @Crostul EDIT: how can I write the Taylor McLaurin series expansion if the function is not defined for x=0?

Comment: @Crostul i mean i should write f = f(0) + f' ... but f(0) is not defined

Comment: As Crostul commented, we do not care about $0$. Just go ahead with the hint given. You will need very few terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=\frac{1}{x}$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}I=\int_{1}^{2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\, dx = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z^2}\,dz &=& \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_{1/2}^{1}z^{2n-2}\,dz\\&=&\color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)n!}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\right)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
The last series converges very fast; moreover, due to alternating signs the approximation error is bounded by the last term considered, and by summing till $n=3$ we get
$$ I\approx {\color{red}{\frac{589}{960}}} = 0.6135\ldots $$
with the approximation error being less than $\frac{1}{20}$.